# get(int) in List cannot be applied to get(Java.lang.string())

Tags: java, collections

I am having a little issue with synatx. For all issues with there:

```
selectButton = emptyButtons.get(field[i][0]);
```

or anything similar I am getting following error

```
 get(int) in List cannot be applied to get(Java.lang.string()).
```

What is the correct syntax to fix this?

Below is the code:

```
private void computerMove() {
    String[][] field = new String[3][3];
    Random random = new Random(); //you may want to declare this as a class field
    List<Button> emptyButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                emptyButtons.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    Button selectButton;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                && field[i][2].equals("")){
           selectButton = emptyButtons.get(field[i][2]);
        }
        else if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                && field[i][1].equals("")){
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(field[i][1]);
        }
        else if (field[i][1].equals(field[i][2])
                && field[i][0].equals("")){
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(field[i][0]);
        }
        else {
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));
        }

    selectButton.setText("O");
    selectButton.setTextColor(playerO);
    turnsCount++;
    isGameOver();

}
```

Comment: The List.get() method expects an integer index, you are passing a String value. If you want to get a specific element, you should probably get the index first (indexOf method) and the the get method.

Comment: Why would it work? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Rcordoval Can you show me how to implement this please?

Comment: @shmosel basically what I want to do is that if I press a button, another button is pressed automation by setting the value of O based on the if conditions

Comment: Too general. What I'm asking is, what did you think `emptyButtons.get(field[i][2])` would do? Don't assume we can understand your code if the compiler can't.

Comment: @shmosel Ah ok I understand what you mean. Basically what I was home was to pin point the button for in column 2 in a row where there are two of the same pieces of text in column 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned already, the problem is with data type mismatch.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)  instead of using [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Following is modified code using `HashMap`:

```
private void computerMove() {
    String[][] field = new String[3][3];
    Random random = new Random(); //you may want to declare this as a class field
    HashMap<Integer,Button> emptyButtons = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                emptyButtons.put(i*3 + j,buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    Button selectButton;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                && field[i][2].equals("")){
           selectButton = emptyButtons.get(i*3 +2);
        }
        else if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                && field[i][1].equals("")){
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(i*3 +1);
        }
        else if (field[i][1].equals(field[i][2])
                && field[i][0].equals("")){
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(i*3);
        }
        else {
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));
        }

    selectButton.setText("O");
    selectButton.setTextColor(playerO);
    turnsCount++;
    isGameOver();

}
```

Comment: I just tested it and even though I get no code errors, if I try to press a button, it causes the application to crash. Is there something else that needs to be changed? Basically when I press a button then another button is pressed automatically by setting the text O and that is based on the if conditions you see

Comment: @Merlin I modified code in view of the provided code snippet. _I can correct what I see_. So you need to post the complete code if you need further help.

Comment: Ok I give a go during my break but if it doesn't work then I'll post an update below my code snippet showing the whole code.

Answer (score -1):

As you explained your syntax is wrong, ArrayList does not have any method like get(String). You need to maintain count so that you can get it using that count.So you need to change your logic here.